# Retake ownership from service account

Tags: google-sheets, gcloud, service-accounts

I've assigned ownership of one of my google sheets to a service account from a gcloud project I am working on (not a smart thing to do, I know...). How can I re-assign ownership of this sheet to my main user account?

Comment: You can log in their account and re-assign to yourself, or make a copy and remind everyone not to use that sheet you assigned?

Comment: @CodeCamper You can't _log in_ as a service account (through the regular sheets web interface), but you can make authenticated calls to the APIs as the service account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have permissions on the service account (e.g. you're owner of the GCP project), you can use the command line tools to authenticate as the service account and modify the permissions there.

Step by step process (you might have already some of those steps done):

1. [Download and install the GCP SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-interactive):

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
exec -l $SHELL
gcloud init
```

2. During the initialization, follow the steps to authenticate with the account owner of the GCP project, and select the project in question. You can ignore the rest of the steps.
3. [Create and download a key for the service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys) that is the current owner of the file (change the service account in this command):

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key --iam-account service_account_id@project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

4. Hack the SDK to include the Drive scope:

```
sed -i 's/\(^CLOUDSDK_SCOPES = (\)/\1"https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/auth\/drive",/' $(gcloud info --format 'value(installation.sdk_root)')/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/config.py
```

5. Activate the service account (change the service account in this command):

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account service_account_id@project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file key
```

6. Make a call to the Drive API giving back the ownership (change the drive file ID and the new owner email address in this command):

```
curl -H"Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/DRIVE_FILE_ID/permissions?transferOwnership=true -d '{"role":"owner","type":"user","emailAddress":"YOUR_EMAIL@example.com"}' -H'content-type:application/json'
```

After these steps, your regular email account should be the new owner.

---

This is a pretty bad solution (hacking the SDK, etc..), but it's barely 7 bash commands, so I think it's likely the fastest/simplest one, at least for a one-off situation.

If this happens often (I guess not), it's likely that a real script would be more useful.

Comment: That worked perfectly. At first I could not get what you mean by Drive File ID, but then, let there be light :) Thanks!

Comment: When I try that, I get {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "ownershipChangeAcrossDomainNotPermitted",
    "message": "Bad Request. User message: \"Sorry, cannot transfer ownership to xxxx. Ownership can only be transferred to another user in the same organization as the current owner.\""
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request. User message: \"Sorry, cannot transfer ownership to xxxx. Ownership can only be transferred to another user in the same organization as the current owner.\""
 }
}

Comment: I'm guessing it's related to trying to assign the file to an account in a different org than the service account. Not sure if this is something that always happens, or if it's an org policy, but either way the way to move forward is to use an account in the same org as the service account (if the GCP org is _example.com_, assign ownership to _user@example.com_).

Comment: both the service account and the account that should be the new owner are in the same organization.

Comment: Then I don't know. It looks like some kind of limitation on the drive side, despite the fact that the script is working properly (it works good enough that it actually gets to the point of trying the ownership change, but it gets rejected). I've searched in Google for the error code (`Ownership can only be transferred to another user in the same organization as the current owner.`), and there's an overload of information. I encourage you to take a look at the answers there, since it seems like this error code could be trigger by multiple factors.